# Insert images into messenger app through another app

Tags: android, list, android-intent

I have an app which contains a variety of stickers and gifs and I want the app to provide a list of messaging apps, the user will select one and it will open it up.

I was hoping someone could give a guideline about how to create a list of select-able apps of my choosing and how to open them through my application.

Answer (score 0):

In android, you can simply throw an implicit intent (see here: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html), but the required apps need to have a common intent filter.

Since, this is quite achievable through [ShareAction](http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/shareaction.html) (See [This](http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send.html) tutorial as well), you are better off googling first, than asking on SO !!